# FrontEndObject::notavail: error when using math

Tags: scripting

I am new to mathematica script and thus I don't know whether this generated error is natural or not.

When I write a command such as `echo "3" | math` in the terminal.
The output generates

```
Mathematica 10.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2014 Wolfram Research, Inc.

FrontEndObject::notavail: 
   A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

In[1]:= 
Out[1]= 3

In[2]:=
```

The output is actually what I expected and seems to work fine. But I am really annoyed by the error

> FrontEndObject::notavail: 
>         A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

Is it a normal behavior?

Comment: Related: "Details" section of [`message/FrontEndObject/notavail`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/FrontEndObject/notavail.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I read the detailed section before I posted this page but I could not understand well. So initializing `math` already requires a front end?

Comment: I don't think it **requires** it absolutely, but as the message says, some things require it.  Like `Dynamic`.   Maybe typesetting and rendering graphics.  I believe the message is a warning not an error. My link was meant to be helpful (to you and anybody else), but it's not meant to be an answer to your Q.  Personally, I would not by annoyed by it.  I can't find the  documentation to the command `math`.  Do you have a link?  Is there an initialization option you could use to turn the message `Off`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually, I appreciated your link. Thanks for that. Regarding to the second question, I could not find a way to turn off the message so far. The warning pops up already when `math` is initialized.